# If security is not an issue, is an immutable interface a good pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interface, immutability

It is commonly suggested that immutable classes should be sealed, to enforce a promise to consumers that observed properties of the class will remain invariant.  Certainly that would seem a good practice for classes that would be employed in security contexts.  On the other hand, there are a number of cases where it may be useful to have a number of immutable classes with common base features, and also have editable versions of such classes.

For example, a graphics program might have a DrawnText object which contains a location, font, and string, and a derivative DrawnFancyText string which adds parameters to curve text around a shape.  It may be useful in some contexts to have immutable versions of those objects (e.g. for things like undo buffers), but in other contexts it may be more useful to have mutable versions.

In such a context, there are some contexts where one will need a readable DrawnFancyText object but not care whether it's mutable or not, but there are others where one will need an immutable derivative of either DrawnText or DrawnFancyText but won't care which.  Achieving the former would require EditableDrawnFancyText and ImmutableDrawnFancyText to have a common base; achieving the latter would require ImmutableDrawnText and ImmutableDrawnFancyText to have a common base.  Unfortunately, such a pattern cannot be achieved without multiple inheritance since ImmutableDrawnText has no relationship to EditableDrawnFancyText.  Fortunately, interfaces do allow multiple inheritance even though classes do not.

It would seem the best way to achieve the proper inheritance relationship would be to define interfaces:

1. IDrawnText

   IDrawnFancyText : IDrawnText

   IEditableDrawnText : IDrawnText

   IEditableDrawnFancyText : IEditableDrawnText, IDrawnFancyText

   IImmutableDrawnText : IDrawnText

   IImmutableDrawnFancyText : IImmutableDrawnText, IIDrawnFancyText

It would seem that having consumers of the class use interfaces rather than classes would achieve all of the proper object relationships.  On the other hand, exposing interfaces would mean that consumers would have to trust that nobody implements a so-called "immutable" interface with an object that allows outside mutation.

For non-security-sensitive information, would it be good to use interfaces so as to allow proper inheritance relations, and rely upon implementers not to violate contracts?

Ideally, it would be possible to expose a public interface well enough to allow outside instances to be passed around, without having to allow outside code to define its own implementations.  If that were doable, that would seem like the optimal approach.  Unfortunately, while one can expose public abstract classes with 'internal'-qualified constructors, I'm unaware of any such ability with interfaces.  Still, I'm not sure the possibility of someone implementing "IImmutableDrawnText" with an object that allows outside mutation is necessarily a real problem.

**Edit**
IDrawnText would only expose getters but not setters, but its documentation would explicitly state that objects implementing IDrawnText may or may not be mutable via other means; IImmutableDrawnText would expose the same members as IDrawnText, but the documentation would expressly state that classes which allow mutation are forbidden from implementing the interface.  Nothing would prevent mutable classes from implementing IImmutableDrawnText in violation of the contract, but any and all such classes would be broken implementations of that interface.

Comment: immutability has _nothing_ to do with security.

Comment: ..and *everything* to do with sanity

Answer (score 6):

There's no such thing as an "immutable interface".  There's an interface that *doesn't declare* methods that mutate the object, but no way for it to *prohibit* mutation.  And allowing mutation allows all the thread-safety and "security" issues that go along with it.

The reason immutable classes should be sealed, is that they make that promise that they can't (normally) be modified once created.  A subclass can break that promise (and LSP along with it), and prohibiting inheritance is the only way to enforce the promise.

BTW, immutability isn't for security.  A language/framework that allows reflection (like, say, C#/.net?) can be used to modify the object virtually at will, ignoring everything the object's done to prevent it.  Immutability mainly just makes that hard to do accidentally.

Comment: Any interface constitutes promises which will be made by any class implementing them, and it is possible for any interface to be implemented in a way which breaks the promises implied thereby.  It would be possible for a collection which implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator to start returning random garbage if a collection is modified while it's being enumerated, but the documentation for IEnumerable expressly says implementations aren't supposed to do that.  Likewise, if the documentation for IImmutableDrawnShape explicitly specifies its properties must be invariant.

Comment: Any interface constitutes promises which *will* be made.  It says nothing about promises which *won't* be made.  Immutability isn't just the lack of ability to mutate; it's a guarantee that those methods *will not exist, ever*.  And you can't enforce that with an interface.  You can't enforce it at all, without prohibiting inheritance.

Comment: I don't care about the documentation for IImmutableDrawnShape unless i want to know how it works.  I *especially* don't care about it if i'm extending some class that extends some class that implements some extension of IImmutableDrawnShape.  Interfaces specify behavior an object *must* have, not behavior it *must not have*.  Sure, you could cause similar problems with IEnumerable and GetEnumerator, but the breakage would be obvious.  When you break a promise of immutability, the breakage is far more insidious.

Comment: Does anything prevent a collection which implements IEnumerable from returning random data if the collection is implied during enumeration?  If the documentation for an interface specifies that classes which do not make a documented promise of immutability cannot legitimately implement the interface, that won't prevent someone from writing a class that claims to implement an interface but does not behave as the interface requires, but that same situation exists with all types of contracts.

Comment: If you don't care about the documentation of an interface, why are you implementing it?  If you don't care about the documentation of a base class, why are you extending it?

Comment: Because the my class is the same thing as the base class, but with the *added* ability to let me change stuff.  If it didn't want to let me change stuff, there's already a way to prohibit that -- by making the class sealed.  That's the expected way.  You can't make any promises about immutability if you allow inheritance, period.  Tucking some crap away in the docs does not constitute prohibition.

Comment: If the properties returned by the interface are sealed, the only way one could break the immutability implied by the interface would be to re-implement the interface with new properties detached from the base ones.  While someone could deliberately construct a rogue class which behaved that way, it wouldn't happen by accident.

Comment: You can't "imply" immutability.  It's an explicit promise, and one that should be enforceable, since breaking it could have far-reaching consequences.

Comment: And what's this about sealed properties?  Last i checked, you couldn't seal anything in an interface; everything's by definition abstract (must-override), which is the opposite of sealed (can't-override).

Comment: If an implementation of an interface implements it explicitly or implements it using sealed properties, then the only way for any class derived from that implementation to override those properties is to re-implement the interface.  So class1:interface and class2:class1 would not allow class2 to violate the interface contract without explicitly re-implementing the interface in a manner that would be obviously "wrong" (since it would return property values that were detached from those of the base class).  Anyone implementing an interface should read the documentation thereof.

Comment: Again...an interface promises what an object *will* do.  It does not, can not, and never has been or will be assumed to promise what the object *won't* do.  I don't care what the documentation says about immutability -- if inheritance is allowed, immutability can not be guaranteed.  It doesn't matter how much fine print you've stuffed into the documentation.  The promise is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

An interface does not define mutability/immutability; rather, it only serves to constrain what the *consumer* can do. Just because an interface does not *expose* mutation facilities does not mean you should assume the object is immutable. For example, `IEnumerable` says nothing about a collection's immutability,  but it is not a mutable interface.

Basically: you would need to define that elsewhere - probably in documentation.

If that way of splitting up the functionality helps with your domain, then: go for it! If it doesn't help, don't force it on yourself unnecessarily (never invent a requirement).

Also: if a type is not `sealed` it can't really claim to be immutable, as the (base) type itself *won't even know* what is possible. Again, this may or may not be a real problem.

Comment: The declaration syntax for an interface implies nothing about outside immutability, but that doesn't mean that the documentation of the interface can't specify such things.  See my edit above, and my comment to cHao.

Comment: @supercat which is exactly my point; in that scenario it isn't the interface providing that guarantee. The same could be achieved via any API.

Comment: If a method accepts a parameter of type IImmutableFoo, then the compiler can reject any attempt to call the method with any type which does not implement IImmutableFoo.  If the only classes implementing IImmutableFoo are those promising to be immutable, this allows for compile-time checking to ensure that methods are only passed objects which promise immutability.  I'm a fan of compile-time checks whenever they're workable, and interfaces would seem the most practical method to enforce such checking.

Comment: As for the possibility that derived types can do evil things, that's true of any unsealed class.  If the contract for a base class specifies that in any properly-written derived class, every call to GetHashCode will always return the same value, that doesn't prevent derived classes from implementing GetHashCode in a manner which would violate that contract.  Nonetheless, it's considered perfectly reasonable for classes like Dictionary to assume that GetHashCode returns an immutable value.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the WPF [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) class for inspiration if you want to implement this pattern.

It is described as follows:

> Defines an object that has a modifiable state and a read-only (frozen) state. Classes that derive from Freezable provide detailed change notification, can be made immutable, and can clone themselves.

Comment: One problem I have with Freezeable is that it unless I'm misreading things, someone who wants to modify such an object that may or may not be shared has to make a defensive copy to avoid having someone else freeze it on him (if nobody else does freeze the object on him, he can assume nobody else will mind if it changes).  I think a copy-on-write wrapper would be a better pattern, though I haven't quite been able to work out the details of how to do it generically.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541192/any-nice-way-to-implement-copy-on-write-proxy

Comment: @supercat - probably true, I'm not suggesting it answers your question (others have done that), just that it may give you some inspiration.  Freezable is a WPF class and I don't think supports multithreaded scenarios.